# gatsby develop works but not build on same project

Tags: node.js, build, graphql, gatsby, production

I have a very simple Gatsby application. I am running gatsby develop on that and it works fine but when I run gatsby build I am getting an error. I am not sure why the develop would work and the build wouldn't. Not sure what I am missing!

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "./layout"

const ProductTemplate = ({ pageContext }) => {
const { product } = pageContext
return (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{product.title}</h1>
    <div>{product.description}</div>

  </Layout>
  )
}

export default ProductTemplate
```

This is the exact error

```
   8 |   return (
   9 |     <Layout>
> 10 |       <h1>{product.title}</h1>
     |                    ^
  11 |       <div>{product.description}</div>
  12 | 


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

  - product.js:10 
  src/pages/product.js:10:20
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
const { createPage } = actions
// Query for all products in Shopify
const result = await graphql(`
  query {
    allShopifyProduct(sort: { fields: [title] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          shopifyId
          handle
          description
          availableForSale
          priceRange {
            maxVariantPrice {
              amount
            }
            minVariantPrice {
              amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
// Iterate over all products and create a new page using a template
// The product "handle" is generated automatically by Shopify
result.data.allShopifyProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
  createPage({
    path: `/product/${node.handle}`,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/product.js`),
    context: {
      product: node,
    },
  })
})
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-node.js`?

Comment: Updated post with gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ProductTemplate` is inside `/pages` folder (it should be in `/templates`). This is causing that Gatsby tries to create pages for each of the files in that directory automatically. In the case where it does so automatically, it doesn't get any context, and hence build fails. This only happens when you run `gatsby build` because during the `gatsby develop` there's no SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering).

`createPage` API is intended to create dynamic pages based on a slug, path, or another unique identifier field, not for known pages like the ones that are inside `/pages` folder.

To fix it, just move your `product.js` to `/templates` and change this:

```
component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/product.js`),
```

To this:

```
component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product.js`),
```

This is because you are creating a template for each product, not a page (like Gatsby understands a page).

[Here's a GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10742) with exactly your issue if you want to follow the full explanation.

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix only part of the issue. Now I am seeing this.  ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

undefined failed

Can't resolve './layout' in '/Users/Test/Downloads/my-gatsby/gatsby-site/src/templates'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that './layout' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: nevermind, I think I know what the issue is here.

Comment: I'm glad to help. This new issue is because, since you've changed your `ProductTemplate` location, you have to rearrange your imports to match a working location.